# The set of isomorphisms from a right coset of the automorphism group $Aut(X)$ in $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

From  ["Lecture Notes in Computer  Science" by Christoph M. Hoffmann](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540114939) , on page 22-

> Theorem 4
>
> Let $X$ and $X'$ be two isomorphic graphs with vertex set $V = \{1 ..... n\}$
>   , Then the set of isomorphisms from $X$ to $X'$ is a right
>   coset of the automorphism group $Aut(X)$ in $S_n$.
>
> Proof:  Let$ X = (V,E)$ and $X' = (V,E')$. Let $\tau$ and $\kappa$ be
>   isomorphisms from $X$ to $X'$, and note that they are permutations in
>   $S_n$. Recall that
>
> $(v,w) \in E$ iff $(v^{\tau},w^{\tau}) \in E'$ iff
>   $(v^{\kappa},w^{\kappa}) \in E'$.
>
> Therefore, $\tau \kappa^{-1}$  is an automorphism of $X$. Thus, $\tau$
>   and  $\kappa$ are in the same right coset of$Aut(X)$.
>
> Conversely, let $\tau $ be an isomorphism from $X$ to $X'$, and
>   $\alpha$ an automorphism of $X$. Then $\alpha \tau$ is again an
>   isomorphism from $X$ to $X'$. So, the right coset $Aut(X)$ is theset
>   of all isomorphisms from $X$ to $X'$.

My questions are-

1. Why $X'$ has $E'$ which is not $E$. Like vertex set$V$,  $X'$ should have same edge set $E$,isn't it? if $X'$ has $E'$ then it should have $V'$ because permutation acts on vertices too.
2. How $\tau \kappa^{-1}$  is an automorphism of $X$
3. Is there an alternative proof of the theorem?

**Example:-**

Let
 $X = (V,E)$ be a graph with vertices $V = \{ 1,..... 5 \} $,

and edges $E = \{(1,2), (1,4), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5) \}$ .

$X$' the graph $(V,E')$, where $V =\{ 1 ..... 5\}$,

and edges $E' = \{(1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5)\}$.

There are two isomorphisms from $X$ to $ X'$, namely $(2,4,5)$ and $(2,5)$.

How $(2,4,5)$$(2,5)^{-1}$ is an automorphism ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If they had the same edge set, they would be the same graph. We could have $E=E'$, but in general this is not the case. The edge set consists of pairs of vertices, and there's no reason for $E$ and $E'$ to have the same pairs.
2. $\tau:X\to X'$ is an isomorphism and $\kappa^{-1}:X'\to X$ is an isomorphism. Composing them gives an isomorphism $X\to X$, which is an automorphism of $X$.

I know of no better way to prove something is a right coset than using the definition of a right coset. That doesn't mean there aren't alternative proofs, but this is the simplest one I can see.

For $\tau$ and $\kappa$ to be in the same right coset we need $\kappa^{-1}\tau$ to be an automorphism, not $\tau\kappa^{-1}$. This is an error in the proof above which is probably the source of your confusion. For your example $(2,5)^{-1}(2,4,5)=(2,5)(5,2,4)=(2,5)(2,5)(2,4)=(2,4)$ is indeed an automorphism of $X$.

Comment: What if $\tau \neq \kappa$, for example, $\tau =(123)$ and $\kappa=(456)$, $n >6$,  I understand  your answer when $\tau = \kappa$.

Comment: @Mike if they're equal it's boring and you get the identity. If they're not equal you get a nontrivial automorphism.

Comment: @Mike by the way the point of an isomorphism is that it preserves edges.

Comment: Matt,I have added an example to my question, would you explain a little elaborately a little  based on that. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike it's not. It should be $\kappa^{-1}\tau$. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MikeSQ Please see my edit.

Comment: what's wrong with $(245)(25)^{-1}$ ? is it wrong that, $(245)(25)^{-1}=(24)(25)(25)^{-1}=(24)$ since  $(24)(25)=(245)$. Also, $(24)$ and  $(25)$ can commute.

Comment: @Mike they do not commute. $(245)(25)=(452)(25)=(45)(25)(25)=(45)$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: @Mike and $(24)(25)=(254)$, not $(245)$.